# How can I change MySQL session database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to change the default Database when the program starts. First, I start with default Database (main_database) and after select some tables, I want to change to another table (second_database).

I use this code but doesn't work:

```
String qlQuery = "USE second_database;";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(qlQuery);
query.getResultList();

Server server = serverService.findById(1);
```

but it seems like getResultList is only for Selects.

How can I solve that problem?

I'm using Spring Boot and JPA.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

Tenancy (to Spring Boot and JPA):
https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jpa-multi-tenancy-example/

Comment: It's possible to do that, but also can you create live views in your "default_database" that includes all the tables you need from "second_database"? This way you can work with the views and don't need to change the db on app level.

Comment: I will work with one parent Database and 31 child Databases with lots of info. Would be fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options, but it all depends on your usecases:

#### 1. Creating live views in "default_database"

You are working with 31 child databases, but do you need access to all their data? If this cannot be answered (e.g. you expect as a future requirement to need access to arbitrary table from one of these 31 databases) live views is a no go.

If it is determined that all the data that you will ever need for your application is - from DB 1 - table A and B; from DB2 - table C; from DB3 - table D and E; and so on - it might be a good approach to create views.
You should also take into account table data size and operations to be performed (e.g. read only or also writes?)

#### 2. Configuring Hibernate for multitenancy:

You can configure hibernate to execute queries in different databases.

You need to take care of the following things:

- the multitenancy strategy - for MySql use [`MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/MultiTenancyStrategy.html#DATABASE)
- the [`MultiTenancyConnectionProvider`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html) implementation which you can pass via hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider property
- the [`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.html) implementation which you can pass via hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver property

You can follow the [official doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) for more details and code samples as well as this excellent [hands-on article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-database-catalog-multitenancy/) by the master himself.

Comment: I will have a basic Index (in this index I will select the child Database), and after this select, I will work in this Database all the time. If I go back and select another Database, the new database will overwrite the oldest connection, and start working in new connection.

The Child DB will be largest. But the users will only do Read actions, but in background, every hour will execute a cycle to update the data of all Child Databases. Best solution for this??

Comment: It sounds like you will be misusing indexes. You should take a look at database views instead.

Comment: I think isn't be a index misusing. I want to explan better my problem: The website will be visible for 31 countries. Every country has his own database, because this database will contains more than 15 tables, and some tables will have more than 10k rows (or more). So i think the best option is to divide the countries. For this reason, I need to change the session database for fast SQLs.

Comment: So the DB schema for all databases is the same, it's just geo-partitioned? The multitenancy article that I've linked to is demonstrating exactly what you're planning to do - separate databases for Asia and Europe. Did you check it out?

Comment: With second option, i searched info into Google and got it!